# Another Accordion not functioning

Tags: joomla-3.x, javascript

I created Accordion HTML code for certain element in Joomla builder, but some of the Accordion is not working. FYI, all the Accordion code is in the same page. For first element is working fine, but the second is not. Even though I used the same method.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    .accordion {
      background-color: #E1F0E6;
      color: #003F77;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 18px;
      width: 100%;
      border: none;
      text-align: left;
      outline: none;
      font-size: 15px;
      transition: 0.4s;
    }

    .active, .accordion:hover {
      background-color: #A3C1AD;
    }

    .accordion:after {
      text-align: justify;
      content: '\002B';
      color: #003F77;
      font-weight: bold;
      float: right;
      margin-left: 5px;
    }

    .active:after {
      content: "\2212";
    }

    .panel {
      padding: 0 18px;
      background-color: white;
      max-height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="accordion">Question</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>Answer</p>
    </div>

    <button class="accordion">Question</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>Answer</p>
    </div>

    <button class="accordion">Question</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>Answer</p>
    </div>

    <script>
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
      acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
          panel.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
          panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
        } 
      });
    }
    </script>

    <button class="accordion">Question</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>Answer</p>
    </div>

    <button class="accordion">Question</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>Answer</p>
    </div>

    <button class="accordion">Question</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>Answer</p>
    </div>

    <script>
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
      acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
          panel.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
          panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
        } 
      });
    }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Anyone can help me for this matters? :)
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to JSE. Are you getting any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Can you clarify why you have tagged this question as Joomla versions: 2.5, 3.x, 3.3, 3.4, and 3.6? What version are you _actually_ using?  I just pasted your snippet into https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_element_classlist_add and it seems to be working for me.  Do you have other scripts interfering? What does your generated source code look like?  Perhaps your demo doesn't accurately represent your actual project html.

Comment: @mickmackusa The problem when I used that code to other element, its not functioning. First element working fine, the second element is not.

Comment: I understand.  We need more information to be able to help you.

Comment: @Miza please provide all requested details.  Otherwise this page will need to be closed as "cannot be reproduced".

Comment: Hi @mickmackusa, I'm trying to paste the code in the comment but cannot send because too long. Kindly try copy my code twice. Then you will notice that the code at the top is not working, but the second code is working fine. Kindly advise

Comment: Please [Edit](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/posts/26605/edit) your question to provide relevant details and correct the question tags.

Comment: @Miza I rejected the above edit because it came from the answerer instead of you.  Despite my rejection, the edit was applied because you approved it.  This _should_ mean that the edit is a 100% accurate portrayal of your actual project code.  If it is not 100% perfect, we need you to edit the question to make appropriate adjustments.  If this does perfectly express your Joomla version and code, I will be happy to Reopen this question -- I just need to get confirmation from you.  When a question is clear and accurate, it invites multiple answers by which you can choose which one is best.

Comment: @mythic Thanks! It work!

Comment: This question is not about Joomla - it's a basic HTML/JS issue, even if it happens to implement this in a Joomla site. Thus, it can not stand in the Joomla Stack Exchange site.  FYI, using multiple instances of the exact same script is a bad practice and usually will make your scripts fail.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be multiple accordions with the same class name if your code is doubled. Create all accordions above javascript at the bottom of the body and it should open all created. I put a row break in to separate the accordions.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
.accordion {
  background-color: #E1F0E6;
  color: #003F77;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover  {
  background-color: #A3C1AD;
}

.accordion:after {
  text-align: justify;
  content: '\002B';
  color: #003F77;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="accordion">Question</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>Answer</p>
    </div>

    <button class="accordion">Question</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>Answer</p>
    </div>

    <button class="accordion">Question</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>Answer</p>
    </div>

    <br />

    <button class="accordion">Question</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>Answer</p>
    </div>

    <button class="accordion">Question</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>Answer</p>
    </div>

    <button class="accordion">Question</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>Answer</p>
    </div>

    <script>
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
      acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
          panel.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
          panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
        } 
      });
    }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How can you make this deduction after we agree that this issue cannot be reproduced with the details provided? How can you confidently fix something that you can't replicate.  This is a blind-guess about what might fix the OP's problem.  Doubling the css and javascript is not an elegant solution. I should have closed this page earlier.  Even if your suggestion fixes the issue, the question lacks clarity and will not invite additional answers (like a good clear question should).

Comment: Creating redundant scripting is definitely not best practice.  If someone wants to resort to less elegant coding practices, they are free to, but I wouldn't be suggesting it.  If someone needs individual styling, you add another class or use `eq` or some other technique to isolate a specific element then add only that extra colour/bg/whatever.  Duplicating whole chunks of css/js or declaring multiple selectors that share exact styles/behaviors is suboptimal.  Classes are designed to be target-able non-unique identifiers; this is a feature to enjoy not avoid.

Comment: I appreciate your toil, but the OP's specific issue is not clear / cannot be replicated.  We have no way of knowing if your suggestion will solve the OP's issue.  It is entirely possible that there is a typo somewhere or some other interference.

Comment: Replicated: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GAP7DFKS4WXQ

Comment: Cool, I didn't know you could make your own save-able demos on w3schools.  In your demo, the first set of elements is not working, but the second set is.  The OP is saying that the first set IS working, but the second set IS NOT.  I think the second js block needs to be removed to replicate it.  https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GAP7QP8RTBM6  In other words, elements are added to the dom AFTER the javascript assigns the listeners to "all" of the elements -- so it is a "time of execution" issue.

Comment: I believe [that comment](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/26605/another-accordion-not-functioning/26614?noredirect=1#comment33757_26605) is referring to the OP trying to implement my suggestion; not the OP's original code.

Comment: Just going by their direction. If you paste answer code in you can see it will clear up all issues with toggle not working. Probably writing different sets of questions and adding the same javascript after each set or leaving javascript at first one and not putting it below the rest. They write them all however they want them arranged on page, then javascript at bottom. If that's not it, good luck to them.